# Can somebody please explain WaitForSeconds()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wait

I am trying to make my code wait `x` seconds before doing something. I looked up how to do this, and found out about the `WaitForSeconds()` function. Unfortunately, whenever I try to use it I get red underlines in my code. I am trying to make it so when you die it waits a few seconds before you respawn:

```
 void Respawn()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    gameObject.transform.position = spawnPoint;
}
```

I also understand I need to put something like `StartCoroutine(Example());` somewhere but I also don't know where to put it. How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);` must be used in a coroutine function. Right now, you are using it in a `void` function `void Respawn()`. Changing the `void` to `IEnumerator`  should fix your problem.

```
IEnumerator Respawn()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    gameObject.transform.position = spawnPoint;
}
```

Then you can call it with  `StartCoroutine(Respawn());`. Each time you call it, it will wait for `5` seconds, then execute `gameObject.transform.position = spawnPoint;`. Visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951904/is-coroutine-a-new-thread-in-unity3d) if you want to learn how it works.

Comment: It seems adding that stops it from doing anything at all?

Comment: Adding **what** stops it from doing anything at all?

Comment: Changing my function to a coroutine function makes the function do nothing.

Comment: That's not true. You must call it with `StartCoroutine(Respawn());` not `Respawn()`. Remember we talked about `Debug.Log` last time? Use it.

Comment: OH, so instead of saying "Respawn()" I say "StartCoroutine(Respawn())"?

Comment: Yes. Please google `Unity coroutine` to learn more about it. It has other functions that is good to know. You can use it to move object over time. You can chain coroutines. Lots of good stuff. You are welcome!