# Trying to understand c# yield in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a class. It has a method that does a lot of work. I would like to not have the program hang while it does the work. I understand `yield` will do this for me.

```
void Start() {
  DoWork(10,10);
}

void DoWork (int x, int y) {
  for (int i=0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < y; j++) {
      // Stuff
    }
  }
}
```

If I add a `yield` like this

```
void Start() {
  DoWork(10, 10);
}

IEnumerable DoWork (int x, int y) {
  for (int i=0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < y; j++) {
      // Stuff
    }
    Debug.Log (1);
    yield return null;
  }
}
```

None of the work gets done and on top of that I see no log statements at all.

How do I `yield` my code so the program doesn't freeze?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Unity3D engine so your coroutine needs to return IEnumerator to be valid:

```
void Start() {
  StartCoroutine(DoWork(10, 10));
}

IEnumerator DoWork (int x, int y) {
  for (int i=0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < y; j++) {
      // Stuff
    }
    Debug.Log (1);
    yield return null;
  }
}
```

This is in no way multithreading. It is run just like an update once per frame between the Update and the LateUpdate except if you use

```
 yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
```

then it is postponed until after the rendering process. What it does is create a new object of type Coroutine and place it on the calling MonoBehaviour stack of coroutines.

This works as a method that performs some repetitive action but always return to the main program when hitting a yield. It will then catch back from there on the next frame.

Comment: Hi @Justin.  I fear you may still be misunderstanding `MonoBehavior` (coroutines) in Unity3D.  Here's an angry essay http://stackoverflow.com/a/35280256/294884

Comment: Also Justin, I ***have deep fears*** that since you talk about doing "work" you are really thinking about threading, not the frame-based concept in a game engine.  The frame loop in Unity (ie "update", or indeed "coroutines" if you prefer - it's absolutely exactly the same thing) is nothing, it is just the frame step through time.  You can't really "split up" work in there, generally, I believe in the way you're thinking.  (Sure, you can of "a few of" some thing in any given frame.)

Comment: Here's a beautiful, elegant .. indeed, you could say witty insightful .. lovely, really .. essay on the matter from some drunk http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1147932/view.html

Comment: @JoeBlow lol.  Reading your Unity comments each morning as I drink my coffee always an entertaining affair :)

Comment: HEH that's awesome.  I'm just drinking some evening cafe unfortunately :/

Comment: Also @Justin808 .. an ***overwhelming point*** over and above everything said here.  I have never seen an actual need to do "threading" or the like in Unity.  I mean it's just a friggin game engine. Performance is fine. All you're doing is throwing some 2D birds around a screen, or letting Mecanim cycle. It's worth noting that in any of these conversations about finding threads, etc, the end result is always "hell, didn't need to bother at all!  What icon will make the most money?!"  So, consider you may just not need any sort of "Work" at all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the StartCoroutine method:

```
void Start() {
  StartCoroutine(DoWork(10, 10));
}

IEnumerator DoWork (int x, int y) {
  // (A)
  yield return null;
  // (B)
  for (int i=0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < y; j++) {
      // Stuff
    }
    Debug.Log (1);
    yield return null;
    // (C)
  }
}
```

Yur code is executed piece by piece where delimiter of steps is the yield operator, i.e. when Framework calls MoveNext() the first time - the code (A) will be executed, when it calls MoveNext() second time - the code (B) will be executed, then  code (C), and so on and so forth.

Comment: I think you are misled by the unity tag, this is not valid for Unity3d engine. That would not even compile. A coroutine must return IEnumerator not IEnumerable. The second part is not at all what Unity3D does for coroutine so I ask you are answering something different.

Comment: This seems to with with the exception that the DoWork method should be `IEnumerator`. Things take just as long as before but the program no longer hangs until it finishes.

Comment: You should remove the second part of your answer as you assume some information that you actually do not know about. They are most likely wrong by the way, Unity coroutine is not multithread.

Comment: I was close to the truth without having any experience with unity3d :)

Answer (score 1):

When you add a `yield` statement, the compiler actually generates a private class that acts as a state machine that implements `IEnumerable`. As such none of the code wrapped up from the original method will be called unless you enumerate the result of the method - in your example, you're throwing away the return value, so nothing would happen.

Comment: rowland, this is specifically bout `MonoBehavior` in Unity3D

Comment: @JoeBlow The answer holds true irrespective of whether this is a console app, or a Unity app - the issue is not understanding what `yield` does or that you have to enumerate its result for it to actually do something.

Answer (score 0):

`Yield` keyword is used for lazy loading/computation support in C#.

Try doing:

```
var result = DoWork().ToList();
```

This forces an evaluation of the DoWork() method and you will see the logging taking place.

Comment: tamas, this is specifically bout `MonoBehavior` in Unity3D

Answer (score 0):

C# yield in Unity works just like C# yield always does. Unity does not influence this in any way.

`yield` is a keyword that is used to allow enumeration over a set of return values.

```
IEnumerator<int> MyEnumerationMethod()
{
    yield return 5;
    yield return 1;
    yield return 9;
    yield return 4;
}

void UserMethod1()
{
    foreach (int retVal in MyEnumerationMethod())
        Console.Write(retVal + ", ");

    // this does print out 5, 1, 9, 4, 
}

void UserMethod2()
{
    IEnumerator<int> myEnumerator = MyEnumerationMethod();
    while (myEnumerator.MoveNext())
        Console.Write(myEnumerator.Current + ", ");

    // this does print out 5, 1, 9, 4, 
}
```

UserMethod1() and UserMethod2() are pretty much the same. UserMethod1() is just the C# syntactic sugar version of UserMethod2().

Unity uses this language feature to implement Coroutines:

When you call `StartCoroutine()` and pass it an `IEnumerator`, Unity stores this enumerator and calls `MoveNext()` for the first time. This will cause `MyEnumerationMethod()` to be called and executed up until the first `yield return`. At this point, `MoveNext()` returns and the first result (5) can be retrieved by looking at the `Current` property of the enumerator.

Now, Unity regularly checks the `Current` property and - depending on its value - decides whether the time has come to call `MoveNext()` again. The value of `Current` might be an instance of `WaitForEndOfFrame`, an instance of `WWW` or whatever, and depending on that the time, `MoveNext()` is called is decided.

Once `MoveNext()` is called again, execution of `MyEnumerationMethod()` will be continued at the point where it was interrupted last time, and executes until the next `yield return` is executed. And so on.

That's all there is to yield, and to Coroutines in Unity.