# Unity C# waiting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wait, coroutine, ienumerator

Currently, I have this code

```
void update()
{
    Debug.Log(1);
    StartCoroutine(wait());
    Debug.Log(4);
}
IEnumerator wait()
{
    Debug.Log(2)
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    Debug.Log(3)
}
```

I want an output of 1, 2, 3, 4, but instead I'm getting 1, 2, 4, 3. I think I may be misunderstanding how coroutines function here. Why am I getting this behaviour and how would I go about fixing it? Thanks in advance

Comment: You could skip the coroutines altogether. A regular function stack would behave the way you're requesting.

Answer (score 1):

To learn more about Coroutines, I recommend reading the excellent answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932306/how-does-startcoroutine-yield-return-pattern-really-work-in-unity).

To give a high-level summary for your code, when you call StartCoroutine on wait(), all of the code until your yield statement will run. So now your output is 1, 2. When yield is called, Unity will return and execute the code in update(), logging the int 4. After 3 seconds it will return to wait() and continue execution, giving the final output 1,2,4,3.

If you want to output 1,2,3,4 you will need to use yield return to call the wait() method, so 4 is printed afterwards. In order to do this the code in update() will need to be in a method of return type IEnumerator itself.

```
void update()
{
    StartCoroutine(dosomething());
}

IEnumerator dosomething()
{
    Debug.Log(1);
    yield return wait();
    Debug.Log(4);
}

IEnumerator wait()
{
    Debug.Log(2);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    Debug.Log(3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but since I need my wait function to perform a similar task in several different sections in my program, is there a way to allow for this sequence of executions without moving code into my wait function?

Comment: Does your wait function have to be called in update(), which cannot be of type IEnumerator? In order to pause the process currently written in update() until wait() returns, that code needs to be within a coroutine too.

Comment: Not really, I just didn't wait to lump code in there because it would look inefficient. But if that's the only way to manipulate the execution sequence, then it'll work fine. Thanks for your help

Comment: In that case yeah, I'd create another method that returns an IEnumerator that (in your example) prints 1, runs wait(), then prints 4, and start that in update(). I've updated my answer above to reflect this.